# Best practice to multiple 'ifs' - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, complexity-theory

I built a function to make a responsive carousel with multiples imgs per slide. (couldn't make Owl Carousel work on my Angular project, but not the point here).

I set the amount of img that will be presented by slide based on the current screen width.

Here is my code:

```
   imgsHistoria = [
    "../../assets/imgs/historia/hist_01.png",
    "../../assets/imgs/historia/hist_02.png",
    "../../assets/imgs/historia/hist_03.png",
    "../../assets/imgs/historia/hist_04.png",
    "../../assets/imgs/historia/hist_05.png",
    "../../assets/imgs/historia/hist_06.png",
    "../../assets/imgs/historia/hist_07.png",
    "../../assets/imgs/historia/hist_08.png",
    "../../assets/imgs/historia/hist_09.png",
    "../../assets/imgs/historia/hist_10.png",
  ];

  imgsHistoriaArray = [];
   resizeCarousel() {
    let images = this.imgsHistory;
    let cut = this.getCut();
    this.imgsHistoryArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i = i + cut) {
      this.imgsHistoryArray.push(images.slice(i, i + cut));
    }
  }

  getCut() {
    if (this.getScreenWidth < 480) {
      return 1
    } if (this.getScreenWidth < 576) {
      return 2
    } if (this.getScreenWidth < 768) {
      return 3
    } if (this.getScreenWidth < 992) {
      return 4
    }
    return 6;
  }
```

The thing is that I have CodeMetrics installed and it's showing that the getCut() function has complexity 10, which is not great. How can I  improve this function?

Comment: _"which is not great"_ - but in all likeliness, also lightyears away from _in any way_ relevant ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array and a loop to reduce the number of if statements:

```
getCut() {
    let widths = [480, 576, 768, 992];
    for(let i = 0; i < widths.length; i++) {
        let width = widths[i];
        if(this.getScreenWidth < width) 
            return i+1;
    }
    return 6;
}
```

Here we define an array containing the widths, loop through until we find the correct value, then return the corresponding number based on its index.

Comment: Thank you! Just need a small change (can't edit your answer, the queue is full): put the array inside the function, with "let": `let widths = [480, 576, 768, 992];` but definetly what I was looking for! –